# Error while using fragment manager

Tags: android

```
package com.c2.layoutsdemo;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;

public class ToDoListActivity extends Activity implements NewItemFragment.OnNewItemAddedListener {
```

Also if I make arraylist and addar adapter final as per example, I get additional errors regarding initialization of arraylist.

```
    ArrayList<String> todoItems;
    ArrayAdapter<String> aa;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_to_do_list);

    FragmentManager fm= getFragmentManager();
    ToDoListFragment todolistFragment = (ToDoListFragment)fm.findFragmentById(R.layout.ToDoListFragment);
```

The above line gives error : ToDoListFragment cannot be resolved or is not a field

```
    todoItems = new ArrayList<String>();
    aa = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,todoItems);


    todolistFragment.setListAdapter(aa);


    }

    @Override
    public void onNewItemAdded(String newItem) {
        todoItems.add(newItem);
        aa.notifyDataSetChanged();

    }

}
```

Comment: ToDoListFragment make sure that this class is there in your project. Or you have imported this in your activity, One thing is your activity should be a fragment activity in order to hold the fragments.

Comment: erroras described in comment 1 is resolved if final keyword is removed but in last line of 2nd segment of code i'm getting error : -> ToDoListFragment can't be resolved or is not a field. In Line:
ToDoListFragment todolistFragment = (ToDoListFragment)fm.findFragmentById(R.layout.ToDoListFragment);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting the fragment by Id, so instead of use

```
R.layout.ToDoListFragment
```

you should use

```
R.id.TheIdOfTheFragment
```

and make sure, in your layout file; your fragment declaration contains and `id` attribute:

```
<fragment android:name="xxx,xxx,xxx.ToDoListFragment"
            android:id="@+id/TheIdOfTheFragment"
            ....
 />
```